# Django ImageField issue

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a similar model

```
Class Student(models.Model):
"""A simple class which holds the basic info
of a student."""

name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='foobar', blank=True, null=True)
```

As we can see photo field is optional. I wanted all the students who have their images saved in the college DB. For that i did this

```
>>> Student.objects.exclude(photo__name=None)
```

But i am getting this error :

```
FieldError: Join on field 'photo' not permitted.
```

So, How can i extract all those students having their photos?

Any sort of help regarding this would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't work because [field lookups](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups) only work on other models. Here, `name` is an attribute on the return value of your `photo` field.

Try this instead:

```
Student.objects.exclude(photo__isnull=True)
```

It is preferred to use `isnull` instead of comparing equality to `None`.

#### EDIT:

[Jeff Ober](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89182/jeff-ober)'s suggestion:

```
Student.objects.exclude(photo='')
```

He says filtering is performed on the actual values stored in DB. In a file field's case the path to the file.

Comment: It doesn't work. It actually returns all the students objects. May be because photo field is actually a photo object like this <ImageFieldFile: None> So, it will always return True.

Comment: The query is executed against the value stored in the database, which is the location of the photo. You might try something like Student.objects.exclude(photo=''). isnull only works when the value is actually stored as null. If the entry is created via admin, it will get a blank value (empty string) rather than null.

Comment: @Jeff: I've added your suggestion. But I have my doubts that empty values will be None/NULL instead of zero length strings. It's not a good idea to set null=True on string columns. Causes ambiguation between None & ''.